# FactoryGirl association Parent can't be blank

Tags: activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to use FactoryGirl to create a test database with an association that is Parent has_many Entries.  At this point, it is throwing the ActiveRecord validation error that Parent can't be blank.  I'm having a tough time with this one and have tried many, many methods of creating this test database with this association.  I think I am close, but I may not be even close and may have basic errors, so any and all advice is much appreciated.

My guess is that the hash { parent_id: :id } is not being passed to the Entry factory.  That would fail the validation.  But, I don't know that that is actually the case and, even if it is, I don't know how to fix it.  Thanks in advance for your help...

The error is:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Parent can't be blank

The RSpec call is:

```
before(:all) do
  rand(11..25).times { FactoryGirl.create(:parent) }
  visit "/parents?direction=asc&sort=parent_blog"  
end
after(:all)  do
  Parent.delete_all
end
```

The Parent model is:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries, :allow_destroy => :true
  validates :parent_blog, presence: true,
              uniqueness: true
end
```

The Entry model is:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  validates :entry_blog,     presence:true,
            uniqueness: true
  validates :parent_id,       presence: true
end
```

The Parent factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :parent do
    sequence(:parent_blog) { |n| "http://www.parent%.3d.com/ss" % n }
    entries { rand(5..15).times { FactoryGirl.create(:entry,  parent_id: :id) } }
  end
end
```

The Entry factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entry do
    sequence(:entry_blog)      { |n| "http://www.parent%.3d.com/ss/entry%.3d" % [n, n] }
    parent_id                   { :parent_id }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following modification to your factory definitions should work. I'll be back later to offer some explanation.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :parent do
    sequence(:parent_blog) { |n| "http://www.parent%.3d.com/ss" % n }
    after(:create) {|parent| rand(5..15).times {FactoryGirl.create(:entry, parent: parent)}}
  end

  factory :entry do
    sequence(:entry_blog)   { |n| "http://www.parent%.3d.com/ss/entry%.3d" % [n, n] }
    parent
  end

end
```

The two changes, introducing the use of `after` in the `:parent` factory and using `parent` instead of `parent_id`, are both examples of RSpec's support of associations, as discussed in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations.

As for why your code didn't work, I can only provide a partial answer at this point. The reason you can't include `entries` as part of the initial parent creation is that you don't have the parent id until the parent record is created, yet you need the parent id to create the entries because of `Entry` validating the presence of `parent_id`. Put another way, `parent_id` hadn't been set when the `entries` block was evaluated in your parent factory.

What I'm not sure of is why you can't replace `parent` with `parent_id` in the entry factory and correspondingly replace `parent: parent` with `parent_id: parent.id` in the `FactoryGirl.create` call in the parent factory. I tried that variant before submitting the above and it failed with:

```
  1) test
     Failure/Error: rand(11..25).times { FactoryGirl.create(:parent) }
     ArgumentError:
       Trait not registered: parent_id
     # ./spec/factories.rb:4:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/factories.rb:4:in `times'
     # ./spec/factories.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./tmp/factory_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./tmp/factory_spec.rb:5:in `times'
     # ./tmp/factory_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'll update this answer again if/when I figure that out.

Comment: I certainly would enjoy hearing that explanation because I don't understand.  The after(:create) makes all kind of sense and, in fact, I had tried that in one of my iterations.  However, the reference to "parent" within factory :entry is something I don't understand.  I assume that it provides/supports the association.  In any case, your recommendations worked wonderfully.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being so long in getting back to you. See updated answer.

Comment: This all works for me and no further follow up is needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I upgraded from factory bot 4.11 to 6.2. I suspect this is because a [factory bot 5 change](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/releases/tag/v5.0.0):
`Changed: use_parent_strategy now defaults to true, so by default the build strategy will build, rather than create associations`

Here's what my parent and child factories look like:

```rb
  factory :parent do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Parent #{n}" }
  end

  factory :child do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Child #{n}" }
    parent
  end
```

I had to change the way I was defining my variables in the spec file.
Instead of:

```rb
let(:parent){ create(:parent) }
let(:child) { build(:department) }
```

Used this:

```rb
let(:parent){ create(:parent) }
let(:child) { build(:department, parent: parent) }
```